# How to render SSRS into PDF and Excel in one call?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

As I understand it, with SSRS we can use ReportingServiceExecutor web service and generate reports dynamically from code. We are using code like this to get the return report in certina format like PDF, Excel

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();

byte[] result = rs.Render(fileFormat, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

This above code calls the SSRS engine, executes the report, calls the underlying stored procedure and returns the result in given fileFormat.

If I want to generate both Excel and PDF report than I will have to call above method twice. This will make 2 DB calls which will be very time consuming.

Is there any way I can do this in one shot ? I want to get some kind of result back and than convert it into PDF & Excel using that.

Zeus

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.